# Dapper: Result from "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName

Tags: dapper

I have the following code:

```
string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName;
var rtn = DapperConnection.Query<int>(sql);
```

This works and bring back 1 record in the rtn variable. When I inspect the variable it seems to have 2 members, one is "[0]" and the other is "Raw View".

The member [0] is of type int and has the expected value, but I can't seem to get to that value in my code.  This seems like a stupid question because I should be able to get to it, but can't.  The latest try was the following:

```
int rtnCount = (int)rtn[0];
```

This however gave me a compiler error.  How do I get to this value in my code?

Comment: `rtn.First()` maybe?

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thank you very much.  You made my day!!!

Answer (score 69):

Please don't do this! It's fragile, and introduces a gaping sql injection vulnerability. If you can return your count for a given table with one line of very expressive code, and no vulnerability, why make it method?

Do this instead:

```cs
DapperConnection.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers");

// You will be happier and live longer if you avoid dynamically constructing 
// sql with string concat.
```

Comment: I take it that "Please don't do this!" does not refer to your own answer, but the example in the original question (?)

Comment: Ha! Never thought of that :-) I'll be clearer the next time.

Comment: It's fine to do this as long as you have complete control over the table name variable. You don't want to do this with user input, though.

Comment: Opinions vary. Personally I can't believe we ever attacked SQL with string methods. It's just aberrant, but it's an industry wide abberation - you don't need to take this personnaly. According to me, [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst) is how we should talk to databases :-)

Answer (score 6):

Use `rtn.First()` — it is an enumeration so that's the general way to get its first (and only in this case) item.